# Unable to generate results with allure / ruby cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, allure

I have been working on a new auto framework in ruby, but I am unable to get allure reporting results created, I have tried various different things but ultimately end up with the following errors:

> `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12177/devtools/browser/498a65da-7ba2-4387-8243-8d0e5be0424e`
>
> `WARNING: The formatter AllureCucumber::Formatter is using the deprecated formatter API which will be removed in v4.0 of Cucumber.`
>
> `undefined method 'name' for #<Cucumber::Core::Test::Step:0x00000000059673a0> (No MethodError)`
>
> `C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/allure-cucumber-0.5.8/lib/allure-cucumber/formatter.rb:121:in 'after_test_step'`
>
> `C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/ignore_missing_messages.rb:11:in 'method_missing'`
>
> `C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:32:in 'block in initialize'`

I have followed the documentation and have good experience using the reporting with java, is it likely my version of cucumber is unsupported? At best I can get an empty results directory created but the cucumber tests always error out with the above message.

Answer (score 0):

This post is 8 months old so hopefully you got it worked out, but incase anyone else lands here, you can patch the cucumber-ruby gem with the following to get your tests to pass:

```
class Cucumber::Core::Test::Step
  def name
    return text if self.text == 'Before hook'
    return text if self.text == 'After hook'
    "#{source.last.keyword}#{text}"
  end
end
```

The warning about API depreciation past 4.0 will remain, though. Hopefully  it will be fixed before then: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumber/issues/63